# How to read Apollo Normalized SQL cache in andorid?

Tags: android, graphql, apollo-android

I am using Apollo Normalized SQL Cache for caching the user data such as user id, name and phone number in Android.  Is there a way that I could fetch that information whenever I need irrespective of the query being fired or not?

The response of the query stored in cache.

```
query loginUser($mobile: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(mobile: $mobile, password: $password){
        token
        id
    }
}
```

ApolloClient.java

```
public class OtherAplClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = AplClient.BASE_URL; 

    public static ApolloClient getmApolloClient() {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

        return ApolloClient.builder()
                .serverUrl(BASE_URL)
                .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here I want to read the cache

```
ApolloClient apolloClient = OtherAplClient.getmApolloClient();
        // Here I want to read the cache
```

Answer (score -2):

What you need is the ApolloStore, see here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/caching/store
The ApolloStore is the cache and can be read by you.

Example from https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/caching/troubleshooting

```
val dump = apolloClient.apolloStore.dump()
NormalizedCache.prettifyDump(dump)
```